# React state component - Cannot read property 'state' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state

I have the following problem - I can't read value from my state, I get the error:

> Cannot read property 'state' of undefined

My class component with a state:

```
class SideNav extends Component {

    state = {
        brand: 'Thule'
    }

    handleToggle = () => this.setState({open: !this.state.open});



    handleBrand = (evt) => {
        this.setState({brand: evt.target.value});
        console.log(this.state.brand); --> WORKS HERE!!!
    }

    searchProducts() {
        console.log(this.state.brand); --> ERROR: cannot read 'state' property of undefined
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className={classes.sideNav}>
                <Button variant={"outlined"} onClick={this.handleToggle} className={classes.sideNavBtn}>Search</Button>
                <Drawer
                    className={classes.drawer}
                    containerStyle={{top: 55}}
                    docked={false}
                    width={200}
                    open={this.state.open}
                    onRequestChange={open => this.setState({open})}
                >
                    <AppBar title="Search"/>
                    <form noValidate autoComplete="off" onSubmit={this.searchProducts}>
                        <TextField
                            id="brand"
                            label="Brand"
                            margin="normal"
                            onChange={this.handleBrand}
                        />
                        <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={this.searchProducts}>
                            Search
                        </Button>
                    </form>
                </Drawer>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default SideNav;
```

I wonder WHY I'm able to read my this.state.bran value in:

```
handleBrand = (evt) => {
        this.setState({brand: evt.target.value});
        console.log(this.state.brand);
    }
```

but NOT in

```
 searchProducts() {
        console.log(this.state.brand);
    }
```

I don't  understand this case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`searchProducts` is a `class method` either `bind` it in `constructor` or use `arrow functions` (like in `handleBrand`). Currently your accessing the wrong value for `this`

```
searchProducts = () =>{}
```

Using `bind`

```
constructor(){
    this.searchProducts = this.searchProducts.bind(this)
}
```

Arrow functions have `lexical this`. By using `this` inside a class method you are accessing the local `scope` of `searchProducts` not the `Component`'s instance

Comment: AAAAh I was so close... Works! Thanks! But Why do I need such a form?

Comment: Updated the answer

Answer (score 2):

`this` works in [confusing ways](https://codeburst.io/all-about-this-and-new-keywords-in-javascript-38039f71780c) in JavaScript. It's not working as intended in `searchProduct()` because you're passing it as a prop to a child component. In your constructor you should bind it to the instance like this:

```js
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.searchProducts = this.searchProducts.bind(this);
}
```